# How to use RxJava Interval Operator

Tags: rx-java

I'm learning about RxJava operator, and I found these code below did not print anything:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable
    .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("onError -> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long l) {
            System.out.println("onNext -> " + l);
        }
    });
}
```

As ReactiveX, `interval`

> create an Observable that emits a sequence of integers spaced by a particular time interval

Did I make a mistake or forget about something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to block until the observable is consumed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Observable
    .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
            // make sure to complete only when observable is done
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("onError -> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long l) {
            System.out.println("onNext -> " + l);
        }
    });

    // wait for observable to complete (never in this case...)
    latch.await();
}
```

You can add `.take(10)` for example to see the observable complete.

Comment: Nice, a clean example of CountdownLatch to boot.

Comment: in Rxjava 2, is there a way to use interval with single?

Comment: yuo can convert the single using `mySingle.toObservable()`

Answer (score 6):

Put `Thread.sleep(1000000)` after the subscribe and you will see it working. `Observable.interval` operates by default on `Schedulers.computation()` so your stream is being run on a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Yeah, it's correct. Interval operator running by asynchronous way, so I need to block abd wait to get result from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As they tell you already interval works asynchronous, so you have to wait for all the events to finish.

You can get the Subscription once you subscribe and then use TestSubcriber which is part of the reactiveX platform, and which will give you the feature to wait for all events terminates.

```
       @Test
public void testObservableInterval() throws InterruptedException {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .map(time-> "item emitted")
              .subscribe(System.out::print,
                         item -> System.out.print("final:" + item));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I have in my github more examples if you need https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java