# What is a clean way to wait for a response?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am sending a message(custom protocol, no HTTP) to my server and want to wait for a response. It is working with the following code:

```
class Connection {

val messages: Observable<Message>
fun sendMessageWithAnswer(message: Message, timeout:Int = 10): Observable<Answer> {
        if (!isConnected) {
            return Observable.just(Answer.NoConnection)
        }

       val result = BehaviorSubject.create<Answer>()
       val neverDisposed = messages.filter {
            it.header.messageId == message.header.messageId
        }
        .map { Answer.Success(it) as Answer}
        .mergeWith(Observable.timer(timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map { Answer.Timeout })
        .take(1).singleOrError()
        .subscribe(
                {result.onNext(it)},
                {
                    // Should never happen
                    throw IllegalStateException("Waiting for answer failed: $it")
                }
        )
        sendMessage(message)
        return result
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution that "neverDisposed" gets never disposed, is this a memory leak?
My other solutions are not working for this test case:

```
    @Test
    fun ImmediateAnswer() {
        prepare()
        val message = ...
        val answerObservable = connection.sendMessageWithAnswer(message, timeout = 1)
        connection.receiveMessage(message)
        val answer = answerObservable.test()
        answer.awaitCount(1)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        Assert.assertEquals(1, answer.valueCount())
        Assert.assertEquals(Answer.Success(message), answer.values()[0])
    }
```

Do you have a cleaner solution for this problem?

Comment: Maybe use a countdownlatch and set it when you receive a message? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652952/how-to-use-rxjava-interval-operator/37658849

Comment: Well, `neverDisposed` will be disposed as soon as there's one of  `onComplete`, `onError` or a matching `onNext` from `messages`. Then it will be disposed of automatically (`take(1)` ensures that unsubscription happens on the first element).